# Proof that e is found in every minimum spanning tree

Tags: graph-theory

Good morning everyone. I failed a graph theory exam last week and I would like to know how to solve some of the problems I got because I don't have any idea. They were mainly proofs and I am very bad at this.
The problem is:

Let $G = (V,E)$ be a convex graph, with $e : E \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ being a cost function, $A$ is a cut in $G$ and $e \in A$ is the only minimum cost edge from $A$. Proof that $e$ is found in every minimum spanning tree from $G$.

I didn't have any idea, tried to say that a min cut has a spanning tree or something like this. I know it may sound strange.
Would you like to help me out please?

Thank you very much and I wish you all a nice day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean **connected**, not **convex** graph.

A cut-set is a set of edges, leaving them causes the increase of the number of components. A cut-set is a **cut** if any of its real subsets are not cut-sets.
Considering *G* is connected, we can exactly divide the vertices of *G* into 2 connected parts, based on the cut *A*. Each edge from *A* has endpoints from both partitions at same time.

The spanning tree should have exactly one edge from *A*. One edge is needed to connect the 2 parts. If it had more than 1, there would be multiple ways between the 2 partitions, because 1 edge could already connect them together. It would mean a circle, that cannot exist in a tree.

Let's suppose that we have a minimal spanning tree *T* of graph *G* without *e*. Call *f* the edge from *A*, which certainly costs more than *e*. *T* is also connected as *G* were. Remove *f* from *T*. Now the vertices are divided into 2 parts as mentioned above. We got 2 subgraph, which are also trees. Since *e* is an element of the cut *A*, its endpoints are in the different partitions. So adding *e* to *T* connects the graph again.

It is a tree, as a result of connecting 2 trees. Also a spanning tree being every vertices connected as in *T* was.

Because we replaced a higher cost edge with a lower one, *T* could not be a minimal spanning tree.

Comment: Thank you very much. It really helped me to understand better this type of problems. I am very sory for the the delay. Have a nice weekend!